# How to prevent a unused fragment from being deleted by proguard?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I can access fragments this way because of the architecture of the application I am working in.

`kotlin val fragment = Class.forName("com.bla.bla.FragmentName").newInstance()`

I don't have a problem in debug mode because there is no proguard.

The team I work with doesn't want me to use the **-keep** rule because it's a very flexible rule. They suggest using **-keepnames** instead, but since I access the fragment via the class name, proguard detects it as unused and removes it.

i.e. adding any rule doesn't change anything because the way we use to access the fragment makes it appear as unused.

Is it possible to pass this fragment through proguard without using keep ?

I'm sorry for my bad english. I hope it explained in an understandable way.

Comment: And simply adding `-keepnames class com.your-package.FragmentName` to your proguard is not working for you?

Comment: No it doesn't work. Because while creating the fragment, I need to use classname. Proguard is deleting this class because it thinks it is not used.

Comment: If they don’t want you to use `-keep` or `@Keep` I think they’re out of luck as those are the only ways to preserve a class that is accessed only by reflection. ProGuard/R8 does preserve classes accessed by a String literal via reflection like in your code above, but I’m guessing that in practice you’re pulling the string from somewhere else.

Comment: At least that’s how I interpret the documentation. https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage